# Deinitialize UIImagePicker - swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a custom `UIImagePicker` that i use from my `viewcontroller`, and set the variable to nil after use.

But when i open it up ones again, and it receives a memory warning i told it to print a line in the console from the `didrecievermemorywarning`.

But the problem is that it prints out from the other instances of `UIImagePicker` that i have set to nil.

And it causes crashes of the app anyway to avoid this?

Comment: Could you please put some coding in so we can see what is causing the error.

Comment: `self.myPicker = UIImagePicker(frame: frame)` when i close i say 'self.myPicker = nil'

Comment: You could try something like `func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: NSDictionary!) {
  self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);` [http://www.raywenderlich.com/76285/beginning-core-image-swift]

Comment: already doing  that it still prints out something + i am using a custom overlay view to capture multiple images